# return a valid in lambda expression of type

Tags: c#, azure, c#-4.0, botframework, chatbot

I have a chatbot using the C# on the bot framework and I am facing an error that says in the Startup.cs file:

> C# Not all code paths return a valid in lambda expression of type func<IserviceProvider,TestBot>,

```
services.AddBot<AlsayerBot>(options =>
{
    var conversationState = new ConversationState(new MemoryStorage());
    options.State.Add(conversationState);
    options.CredentialProvider = new ConfigurationCredentialProvider(configuration);
});
```

Comment: An expression of type [`Func<IServiceProvider,TestBot>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0) gets an `IServiceProvider` as a parameter and returns a value of type `TestBot`. Your lambda expression does not (yet) return a `TestBot`.

Comment: PS: C# is case sensitive. `func` is something different than `Func`, `IserviceProvider` is something different than `IServiceProvider`, etc. This might seem pedantic, but you better get used to it, because the compiler is pedantic as well. ;-)